# Running BLAST through XGrid

Tags: cluster-computing, bioinformatics, blast, xgrid

Does anyone have any experience running BLAST with XGrid?

Googling reveals a tool called 'Xgrid BLAST' existed but not where to get.

Answer (score 0):

BLAST is included with Xgrid. Quoting from "[Utilization of a Local Grid of Mac OS X-Based Computers using Xgrid](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/HPDC.2004.40)":

> Xgrid includes a powerful,
>   customizable, general-purpose job
>   submission interface and Xgrid BLAST,
>   a fully functional, grid-enabled
>   application based on Xgrid technology
>   that runs instances of the NCBI BLAST
>   local alignment search algorithm tool.

After you have installed Xgrid, you can open `/Applications/Xgrid BLAST.app` on any client computer.

For more information, see:

- the [Xgrid installation documentation](http://www.macos.utah.edu/documentation/administration/xgrid/xgrid_presentation/installation_and_use.html) by the University of Utah.
- [How to use Apple's xgrid for running BLAST jobs](https://www.nacs.uci.edu/rcs/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/HOWTO_xgrid) by the NACS Research Computing Support Group
- [Xgrid basics](https://www.wiki.ed.ac.uk/download/attachments/68630442/xgrid_basic.pdf) by the Blaxter Lab at the Institute of Evolutionary Biology, University of Edinburgh. It includes a sample [Perl file](https://www.wiki.ed.ac.uk/download/attachments/68630442/xgrid_blast.pl) to submit BLAST jobs to Xgrid.

Final tip, if you have any bioinformatics related questions on the future, there is a StackOverflow clone specifically geared towards bioinformaticians called [BioStars](http://www.biostars.org). You might get a quicker answer there.